# Default file extensions in .bash_profile

Tags: macos, file-extension, .bash-profile

I use Mac OS Lion and I would like to declare in my .bash_profile the file extensions and the default application to open them.

For example, I want to associate all .txt files to TextMate so that when I shall open the file from the shell it would automatically launch TextMate and opens my file.

Comment: Issue `textmate file.txt` and I'm sure it works as you intended. That you can't just issue `file.txt` like that has to do with permissions for execution - it would be an ambiguous operation. If you want to _run_ a script, you might just type `~/bin/myscript`. But if you'd like to _edit_ the same script, with your proposed system you would type the same thing. It would not make sense. A file ending such as `.txt` is really not fundamental to the file in question. It would bring complexity and more problems for a very small gain. I recommend just getting used to writing `textmate file.txt`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Actually what I would like to be able to do is to type in shell something like: 'open filename' and get the appropriate application open the filename in question.

Comment: On Linux, this can be done with [`xdg-open`](http://portland.freedesktop.org/xdg-utils-1.0/xdg-open.html) ([better info here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xdg-open)).

Comment: @DanielAndersson The `textmate` command doesn't exist. I'm sure you meant `mate`?

Comment: @slhck: Very likely, I was just guessing (I don't have a Mac).

Answer (score 2):

You don't set this association in your `.bash_profile`. Your shell does not know which OS X application to open a file with – it's the [*Launch Services*](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Reference/LaunchServicesReference/Reference/reference.html) that take care of this.

The easiest way to globally change file type associations to certain applications is to install [RCDefaultApp](http://www.rubicode.com/Software/RCDefaultApp/) and just set everything through *System Preferences*.

In theory, you could also modify the `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.LaunchServices.plist` file for custom associations, but I wouldn't recommend going there.

> I want to associate all .txt files to TextMate so that when I shall open the file from the shell it would automatically launch TextMate and opens my file

Go to a text file, right click it and select *Open With…*. Here, choose *TextMate*, and then click *Change All…*.

[image]

Now, whenever you're in the shell, you can type:

```
open foo.txt
```

And this will open TextMate with your text file.<sup>1</sup> The same applies to any other association you might set through either RCDefaultApp or the *Get Info…* dialog in Finder. The magic behind this is that `open` wil defer the call to the Launch Services, which then decide on the application to use.<sup>2</sup>

<sub>1: Actually, for TextMate, the following is enough: `mate foo.txt`</sub>
<sub>2: You can also manually choose an app, e.g. `open -a Xcode foo.txt`. Read `man open` for more.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

I use [duti](http://duti.org) for that. It basically just modifies `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.LaunchServices.plist` but doesn't require you to know the UTIs of filename extensions or restart to apply the changes. Here's a part of my configuration file.

```
# .txt, plain text files without an extension
com.apple.TextEdit public.plain-text all

# executable scripts
com.macromates.textmate public.unix-executable all

com.apple.Preview .jpg all
com.macromates.textmate .rb all
net.sourceforge.skim-app.skim .pdf all
org.videolan.vlc .mkv all
org.videolan.vlc .mp4 all
```

Filename extensions that are included in UTI declarations are converted to UTIs automatically, so `.jpg` also applies to `.jpeg`.